# Making multiple pipes

Tags: c, pipe

I am trying to create a process where several other processes talk to this main one, and I am using pipes to accomplish this. I can get two pipes to work with my current method but as soon as I introduce a 3rd pipe, the program starts to malfunction which I think is due to the reading from individual pipes being blocking functions. Altogether, I am going to need to have 5 receiving pipes and 2 of those receiving pipes will need a sending pipe with them to echo back info. Altogether, this needs a total of 7 pipes. I am very new to Linux and programming in general; I am sorry if this doesn't make sense.

```c
    mkfifo(ECHO_COMMAND_PIPE, 0666);
    mkfifo(READ_COMMAND_PIPE, 0666);
    mkfifo(READ_MATH_PIPE, 0666);
    
    
    
    if ((echo_command_pipe = open(ECHO_COMMAND_PIPE, O_WRONLY))==-1){
        fprintf(stderr, "echo_command_pipe creation failed");
    }                                       
    else if ((read_command_pipe = open(READ_COMMAND_PIPE, O_RDONLY))==-1){
        fprintf(stderr, "read_command_pipe creation failed");
    }
    else if ((math_pipe = open(READ_MATH_PIPE, O_RDONLY))==-1){
        fprintf(stderr, "math_pipe creation failed");
        return 1;
    }
    int error_cnt;
    while(1){
    
        fflush(stdout);
        fflush(stdin);
        int command_read = read(read_command_pipe, command_buffer, sizeof(command_buffer)-1);
        int math_read = read(math_pipe, math_buffer, sizeof(math_buffer)-1);
        command_buffer[command_read] = '\0';                            
        math_buffer[math_read] = '\0';
                                        
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", math_buffer);
        
        
        if (strlen(command_buffer) < 1){
            write(echo_command_pipe, err_buffer, strlen(err_buffer));
            error_cnt = error_cnt + 1;
        }
        else {
            write(echo_command_pipe, command_buffer,strlen(command_buffer));
            error_cnt = 0;
        }
        
        if (error_cnt > 7) break;
        
    }
    
    close(echo_command_pipe);
    close(read_command_pipe);
    close(math_pipe);
    
    unlink(ECHO_COMMAND_PIPE);
    unlink(READ_COMMAND_PIPE);
    unlink(READ_MATH_PIPE);
    
    
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're up to, but it seems likely that you'll need to use `select()`, `poll()` or `epoll()` to determine which of the FIFOs has data available to be read.  This will allow you to deal with the other programs not working in lockstep with your main program and each other.  If you're learning how to program Linux, you might want to think about something a little simpler than managing 7 pipes to start with.

Comment: You should never `fflush(stdin)`.  I could be wrong but I believe that it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @DanielWalker `fflush(stdin)` is undefined [7.21.5.2 The fflush function(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2p2), but there is one compiler maker that does not follow the standard and defines `fflush(stdin)` for general use on input streams as an extension -- 3 guesses which compiler maker does that (your first 2 guesses don't count, cough MS) gcc does something different still and defines `fflush(stdin) - "For input streams associated with seekable files"` (e.g. a file redirected on `stdin`). So standard says undefined, but check your compiler for specifics.

Comment: your opening FIFOs rather than pipes.  Suggest using [pipe](https://linuxhint.com/pipe_system_call_c/)  to define your pipe communications